# How to Set Postman Test Equal to This or That

Tags: testing, automated-tests, postman, postman-collection-runner

I am writing an API test in Postman, and I would like it to succeed if a `Number` is returned or the string `"NA"`.

Based on my current understanding one condition can be tested at a time, like:

```
pm.test('Qty returned is number', () => {
  pm.expect(typeof parseInt(pm.response.json().qty)).to.be.not.equal('NaN');
});
```

Writing as two separate tests, one will pass and one will fail.

How can I code this exception into a single test?

Comment: You could add a second line in that test function to make it a single test?

Comment: Can an `or` condition be set?

Comment: I guess, maybe somewhere but wouldn't having another line in there, check the 2 things separately? If one fails, the test fails. If they both pass, the test passes. Isn't that what you're after?

Comment: Not really... I would like to `PASS` when returned property is a `Number` or is the string `"NA"`.

Comment: Maybe I'm just confused, I don't really understand how a single property, in a JSON schema, can be either a string or an integer. Unless the 'number' is returned as a string.

Comment: Ah, I see the confusion now. Yes, it is an integer returned the the client as a string.

Comment: So it's a string, it might look like a number but the type is string.

Comment: Do you have any recommendations for how to test this condition?

Comment: Not really sure, I don't know the full implementation details of the API to even know if it was the right test. Sorry, I don't really want to suggest some not really useful.

Comment: mabye use:  to.be.oneOf([ , ]);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Worked for my case, wanted the test to pass if one of two values is returned:

```
.to.be.oneOf(["value1","value2"]);
```

> answer from [jaikl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7424326/jaikl)